# Comodules as a functor category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, coalgebras

Let C be a comonoid in some preadditive monoidal category $\mathfrak{C}$, then how can we express the category of C-comodules, in terms of some sort of functor category?

I mean is there a similar expression for $^C\mathscr{M}$ as there is for $_CMod$ (or a monoid $C$) which can be expressed as $Add(C:\mathfrak{C})$?

Comment: Looks cleaner now :)

Comment: Probably there won't be an easy functor category description. Remember that limits of comodules are quite complicated.

Comment: Its ok.. I think I have a nice workaround using a slice category of the specific category I was trying to work with :)

As always thanks Martin :D